# How to install/compile module in Debian without using Full Kernel, only by using the already installed kernel headers

Tags: debian, kernel, compiling

Can someone explain **step by step** how to install a module on a kernel with headers installed? I have Debian with Kernel 3.19.0 for banana pi from http://www.igorpecovnik.com/2014/09/07/banana-pi-debian-sd-image/comment-page-2/#comment-4729 and would like to install the smi2021 module needed for somagic easycap from https://github.com/jonjonarnearne/smi2021.

**So there are 2 options:**

**1) Install module with full kernel source**, by downloading kernel 3.19.0 from kernel.org - This does not work as the custom modules from debian-kernel3.19.0-bananapi are not compatible with the kernel from kernel.org

**2) Install module without full kernel**, with only using the already built in kernel headers. - I would like to use this option as I already have the kernel headers installed.

So can anyone show how to install step by step kernel modules with kernel headers already installed?

I tried to do as said in the comment from blog post posted above but can't do it. I get stuck at step 2: copy from /boot the config file to .config in /usr/src/linux

Comment: Did you check that your hardware is supported first? See http://linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/Easycap

Comment: Hi Faheem! Sure, I have checked. My device is 1c88:0007 Somagic Easycap based on the SMI-2021. I need to install the module in order for it to work. I also tried the method of building kernel from http://code.google.com/p/easycap-somagic-linux/wiki/BuildingKernelModule but since I do not have the full kernel, only the headers, and do not know how to install the module with only the kernel headers.

Comment: Well, there a number of ways you could go. Take the kernel including the module you want, and build it as a Debian binary image, using `kernel-package`. Or you try to do a local build of just the module against your existing kernel. Or you could try Debianizing that module (assuming nobody else has done it) and install the module as a binary Debian package. Think about how you want to do it, and how much work you want to put into it.

Comment: Thanks Faheem! I would like to do it in the simplest way possible, so I think a local build of just the module against my existing kernel will be enough. Can you please tell me step by step how can I do that? Because I am unable to find any tutorials that will explain clearly what should I do. And I also tried the steps from http://www.igorpecovnik.com/2014/09/07/banana-pi-debian-sd-image/comment-page-2/#comment-4729 but got stuck on step 2 (I am a newbie).

Comment: Basically, I need to install this module (the whole smi2021 folder) https://github.com/jonjonarnearne/smi2021/tree/smi2021v3-wip/drivers/media/usb/smi2021 and its dependencies located at https://github.com/jonjonarnearne/smi2021/tree/smi2021v3-wip/drivers/media/i2c ( only saa7115.c )

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to do that either. Do you first want to compile the `i2c` thing?

Comment: yes. First I need to install the i2c dependency and the move on to smi2021

Comment: Ok. I doubt I can help with that, at least not without significant effort, but what does typing make in the `i2c` directory give?

Comment: What's the output of `dpkg -l linux\*`? (This will help determine whether you have the linux-headers package installed, and if so which one...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can go with full kernel source tree, here are the steps I have followed in order to compile and install a driver on the source tree:

Lets say you have the kernel sources extracted at /sources/linux-3.19

1. cd /sources/linux-3.19
2. make mrproper
3. make menuconfig

   *Here make sure to select your driver with "m" label. For instance, if you select to build and install atl1c driver, the config file produced as a result of the above command, .config,  should have the following line:
     CONFIG_ATL1C=m
   Choose the right driver for your case and make sure to label it with "m".*
4. make prepare
5. make
6. make modules
7. make modules_install
8. shutdown -r 0

   *Check to see if the driver is installed*
9. lsmod

Comment: I have tried this but got another error. Please see: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/197086/make-does-not-compile-modules-error-building-modules-stage-2-modpost-0-modul