# Make does not compile modules. Error: Building modules, stage 2. MODPOST 0 modules

Tags: debian, compiling

I have banana pi and installed debian with kernel 3.19.3-bananapi from http://www.igorpecovnik.com/2014/09/07/banana-pi-debian-sd-image/

So I want to compile a module so I downloaded kernel from kernel.org and when I try to compile any module, like for example I am in the root of kernel tree and execute `sudo make M=drivers/android modules`

I get error:

```
Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 0 modules
```

Here is the output with the deubuging V=1

```
user1@bananapi:~/linux-3.19.3$ sudo make M=drivers/android modules V=1
test -e include/generated/autoconf.h -a -e include/config/auto.conf || (       \
        echo >&2;                                                       \
        echo >&2 "  ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid.";           \
        echo >&2 "         include/generated/autoconf.h or include/config/auto.conf are missing.";\
        echo >&2 "         Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix it.";      \
        echo >&2 ;                                                      \
        /bin/false)
mkdir -p drivers/android/.tmp_versions ; rm -f drivers/android/.tmp_versions/*
make -f ./scripts/Makefile.build obj=drivers/android
(cat /dev/null; ) > drivers/android/modules.order
make -f ./scripts/Makefile.modpost
  find drivers/android/.tmp_versions -name '*.mod' | xargs -r grep -h '\.ko$' | sort -u | sed 's/\.ko$/.o/' | scripts/mod/modpost   -i ./Module.symvers -I drivers/android/Module.symvers  -o drivers/android/Module.symvers -S -w  -s -T -
```

I have tried to change the GREP_OPTIONS='--color=always' to never and auto and got the same error.

the output of uname -r is 3.19.3-bananapi
My headers are installed.

The output of dpkg -l linux*

```
user1@bananapi:~/linux-3.19.3$ dpkg -l linux\*
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=================================
ii  linux-dtb-3.19 2.6          armhf        Linux DTB, version 3.19.3-bananap
un  linux-firmware <none>                    (no description available)
un  linux-headers  <none>                    (no description available)
un  linux-headers- <none>                    (no description available)
ii  linux-headers- 2.6          armhf        Linux kernel headers for 3.19.3-b
un  linux-image    <none>                    (no description available)
un  linux-image-2. <none>                    (no description available)
ii  linux-image-3. 2.6          armhf        Linux kernel, version 3.19.3-bana
un  linux-kernel-h <none>                    (no description available)
un  linux-kernel-l <none>                    (no description available)
ii  linux-libc-dev 2.6          armhf        Linux support headers for userspa
un  linux-modules- <none>                    (no description available)
un  linux-sound-ba <none>                    (no description available)
ii  linux-u-boot-3 2.6          all          Uboot loader
un  linux32        <none>                    (no description available)
```

Answer (score 2):

If these are external modules, try building against the kernel first, then install using `modules_install` as described below. Make sure you are building in the path to your kernel source.

From https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kbuild/modules.txt

> --- 2.1 Command Syntax
>
> The command to build an external module is:
>
> ```
>   $ make -C <path_to_kernel_src> M=$PWD
> ```
>
> The kbuild system knows that an external module is being built  due
>   to the "M=" option given in the command.
>
> To build against the running kernel use:
>
> ```
>   $ make -C /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build M=$PWD
> ```
>
> Then to install the module(s) just built, add the target
>     "modules_install" to the command:
>
> ```
>   $ make -C /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build M=$PWD modules_install
> ```

`modules_install` explained:

> `modules_install`
>         Install the external module(s). The default
>   location is       `/lib/modules/<kernel_release>/extra/`, but a prefix may
>         be added with INSTALL_MOD_PATH (discussed in section 5).

---

If you intend to install the module in a custom directory under your main kernel directory (instead of `/extra`), use `INSTALL_MOD_DIR`.

> --- 5.2 INSTALL_MOD_DIR
>
> External modules are by default installed to a directory under
>     /lib/modules/$(KERNELRELEASE)/extra/, but you may wish to   locate
>   modules for a specific functionality in a separate    directory. For
>   this purpose, use INSTALL_MOD_DIR to specify an   alternative name to
>   "extra."
>
> ```
>   $ make INSTALL_MOD_DIR=gandalf -C $KDIR \
>          M=$PWD modules_install       
>   => Install dir: /lib/modules/$(KERNELRELEASE)/gandalf/
> ```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried the following command in the linux-3.19.3 folder: sudo make -C /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build v=1 M=$HOME/linux-3.19.3/drivers/android modules and got the following error: make: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.19.3-bananapi'
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 0 modules
scripts/mod/modpost: 1: scripts/mod/modpost: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
make[1]: *** [__modpost] Error 2
make: *** [modules] Error 2
make: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.19.3-bananapi'

Comment: I just tried the following: make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$PWD. $PWD
and got: user1@bananapi:~/linux-3.19.3$ make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$PWD. $PWD
make: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.19.3-bananapi'
make: Nothing to be done for `/home/user1/linux-3.19.3'.
make: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.19.3-bananapi'   I also tried: ~/linux-3.19.3/drivers$ make INSTALL_MOD_DIR=android -C $KDIR \ M=$PWD modules_install
 and got make: ***  M=/home/user1/linux-3.19.3/drivers: No such file or directory.  Stop.  Sorry but I am a newbie.

Comment: Sorry for the bad visual in the comment, but it's just `make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$PWD`

Comment: Here is what it gave me:

root@bananapi:/home/user1/linux-3.19.3# make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$PWD
make: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.19.3-bananapi'
  CC      kernel/bounds.s
  GEN     /home/user1/linux-3.19.3/include/generated/bounds.h
  CC      arch/arm/kernel/asm-offsets.s
  GEN     /home/user1/linux-3.19.3/include/generated/asm-offsets.h
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `/home/user1/linux-3.19.3/missing-syscalls', needed by `__build'.  Stop.
make: *** [_module_/home/user1/linux-3.19.3] Error 2
make: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.19.3-bananapi'

Comment: Sorry, I was mistaken earlier. `M=$PWD` will use your current working directory. You should `cd` to your module source directory where the `Makefile` is located prior to running the command.

Comment: I went to the android directory, where the Makefile is and did the comand you sent earlier and this is what I got: user1@bananapi:~/linux-3.19.3/drivers/android$ sudo make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$PWD
make: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.19.3-bananapi'
  LD      /home/user1/linux-3.19.3/drivers/android/built-in.o
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 0 modules
scripts/mod/modpost: 1: scripts/mod/modpost: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
make[1]: *** [__modpost] Error 2 make: *** [modules] Error 2 make: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.19.3-bananapi'

Comment: What is the module you are trying to install? Where can I find it?

Comment: The modules is stk1160 and is located in drivers/media/usb/stk1160 in kernel.3.19.3 from kernel.org you can also view it here: https://github.com/jonjonarnearne/smi2021/tree/smi2021v3-wip/drivers/media/usb/stk1160 but not only this module is not installing. More random modules like the modules android from drivers/android also can not be installed. while others like bluetooth modules can be installed . SO I do not know why some modules can be installed while others not. By the way I am accessing the banana pi via putty, over lan cable.

Comment: If you just want that module, then you should be running it from the `stk1160` directory so it will run this `Makefile` https://github.com/jonjonarnearne/smi2021/blob/smi2021v3-wip/drivers/media/usb/stk1160/Makefile Otherwise, did you already follow this README? https://github.com/jonjonarnearne/smi2021

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if there's a `/proc/config.gz` on the banana *when the system is running* (it will not be there if it is not).  Most likely it does exist.<sup>1</sup> Copy that into the top level of the source tree and:

```
make clean
gunzip -c config.gz > .config
make oldconfig
```

Then try building the module again.

---

1. If it doesn't, try `sudo modprobe configs` and check again.  If you got an error trying to load that module (see `man modprobe`) because it doesn't exist, you are out-of-luck.

Comment: Thanks! I just did this and when I tried to do sudo make drivers/android modules I got the same error: 
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 0 modules
But when I did another random module, it worked. for the bluetooth module it worked. make M=/drivers/bluetooth modules works fine. I have noticed that on some modules the compile process works great but on others I get the Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 0 modules error. And on the modules which I need I get the error. I did not modify any files. The kernel is original from kernel.org.

Comment: /proc/config.gz only exists if you have set a flag when configuring the kernel -- although that flag may be set when the kernel was first compiled by the maintainer of the distro. Also look for .config under /usr/src in the kernel source tree.

Comment: It can also be modular, ie., requires `modprobe configs`; when/if that loads `/proc/config.gz` will be available (edited).